# PyCharm seems to think a str object is a float

Tags: python, pycharm

Here is my code (python 3):

```
user_in = input("What are the different values this can take? Separate each with a semi-colon ;\n\t").strip().lower()
# e.g. "strength;alertness ; wisdom; grace;"
options = user_in.split(';')
tidy_options = list()
for op in options:
    tidy_options.append(op.strip())
options = list(tidy_options)
```

but PyCharm (2017.1.5) raises a warning for the `op.strip()` command, warning me:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'strip' for class 'float'
```

I don't see why op is not a `str` type (*and therefore has the `.strip()` method*). I especially fail to see where PyCharm got this `float` idea from. Any help?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input you are giving?

Comment: the best way is to print out the every type of variable after the assignment. reason is when we used some built-in functions some of them changed the type of the variable.

Comment: @user3738936 "strength;alertness  ; wisdom;   grace;"

Comment: If you run the code in command line works well? And in pycharm, it is only a warning or if you run the code fail?

Comment: No it seems to work fine (as I'd expect) but I'm just trying to understand what PyCharm thinks I'm doing. Also I hate warnings, it feels like I'm doing something dodgy!

Comment: So you have this code in a file by itself, nothing else in the file, no import or docstrings, and you are getting that warning in the IDE?

Comment: When you are running the code and it works fine, is that on the command line or inside of PyCharm? If you are running it on the command line, make sure your PyCharm `Project Interpreter` is pointing to the same place `Settings | Project | Project Interpreter`

Comment: try printing the list and each value before the error occurs, also try printing the types of the values. Does it say `float` still?

Comment: I don't know Maxxik CZ, this was years ago! I tried repeating and testing the types for this code in the command line in Windows powershell (using python 3.7.3) and I can't see any bugs or weird behaviour, the items are all strings (including type(op.strip()) == str). So it looks like that was just a bug with PyCharm. It's probably fixed now for all I know